# regular expression to validate only allow -1 and all other positive integers

Tags: asp.net, regex

i need a regular expression to validate only allow `-1` and all other positive integers.any other negative value other than `-1` is not allowed.
i've the following which only allow integers but need to allow -1 as well.plz help

```
^\d+$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `^(-1|[1-9]\d*)$`?

The reason for the `[1-9]\d*` is to not allow 0 (because you said "positive integers").

If you want to allow 0 just do `^(-1|\d+)$`.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest would be ( assuming 0 is fine):

```
^(-1|\d+)$
```

You might want to investigate if you really want to use regex though. It can be easily done with Int.TryParse or something and validating it is greater than -1 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use an alternation

```
^(?:\d+|-1)$
```

Means match `\d+` OR `-1`